# IPVanish VPN and port 1433 to cloud SQL Server

Tags: networking, sql-server, vpn, firewall

I have a client using some software that I wrote, which requires access to a cloud/shared SQL Server via port 1433. He would like to use IPVanish for reasons that have nothing to do with my software. My software cannot connect to his shared SQL Server account when his VPN is connected (via IP Vanish's servers).

My question:
Is it likely that the shared SQL server host (arvixe in this case) is blocking access from IPVanish's IPs on that port due to abuse (hackers trying to hack that host under the anonymity of IPVanish?) Or, is IPVanish likely blocking all 1433 connections?

I have reached out to IPVanish and their T1 tech support doesn't know anything / doesn't understand the question. Also, another option may be if I could somehow configure his router to direct 1433 traffic NOT thru the VPN? Not sure where to start with that... i'm a software engineer and not much of a network guy. Is this even possible? I have options for altering the software to use his primary adapter only. But, seeing this as a last resort since it could be a negative thing for other clients in different setups.

Comment: Why would using his primary adapter be a bad thing? And why would other clients have to do the same? Just add an option to your software where the user can select what interface to use.

Comment: Going down the road of... too many configuration options which means, more that can break, more explanations, more support etc.

I can do that, sure. But, I'd rather spend some time seeing if I can point him in a self-supporting direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me start by stating that I don't mean for this to sound like it likely will. If you developed software for a third party, why is troubleshooting an unrelated issue your responsibility? The issue is not with your software.

That being said, troubleshooting this would likely be by finding another public IP that is has port 1433 open, and see if you can nmap or use another port tester to verify if the port is open. If you can find a few public IPs that should have port 1433 open, but they don't work behind the IPvanish, then you have something concrete to bring to their support. Conversely, if you find that other public IPs show that port open, you can guess that it would be your SQL provider that is blocking it.

Routing one connection outside of the VPN is possible, but I am not familiar with VanishIP. How you may get a connection to go around it would likely involve a manual route being added to the client to redirect the traffic.

Comment: In the world of not-working-for-a-large-company as a W2 employee, the professional services / design contracts aren't always so cut and dry. Troubleshooting was part of the contract to a point. Other IPs indeed had port 1433 open. The issue turned out to be the hosting provider doesn't allow access from IPVanish's servers. In lue of charging for more development to make this work seamlessly (custom .net SQL driver code for choosing the adapter), the client eventually decided to switch from IP Vanish to another provider. Thanks for the troubleshooting steps!